# How best to extract branches from nested arrays for eventual use with ng-repeat directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.
I have a decision data tree of variable depth. The data tree is made of a nesting of individual nodes, each representing a condition to be evaluated. The definition of a node is pretty much standard. See json example below:

```
exampleTree = [{id: 1, 
               condition: 'bla', 
               sequence: 1, 
               tree: [{id:8, 
                       condition: 'more bla', 
                       sequence: 1, 
                       tree:[...]},
                      {id:34, 
                       condition: 'another bla', 
                       sequence: 2, 
                       tree:[...]} 
                      ]
               },
               {id: 25, 
                condition: 'blabla', 
                sequence: 1, 
                tree: [{id:85, 
                        condition: 'more blabla', 
                        sequence: 1, 
                        tree:[...]},
                       {id:41, 
                        condition: 'another blabla', 
                        sequence: 2, 
                        tree:[...]} 
                          ]
               },
               ...
               ]
```

Each branch have the same length, equal therefore to the depth of the tree.

The client wants the data tree to be represented in a table format as follows:

```
| Condition Lvl 1 | Condition Lvl 2 | Condition Lvl 3 |...|
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|---|
| bla             | more bla        | ...             |...|
| bla             | another bla     | ...             |...|
| blabla          | more blabla     | ...             |...|
| blabla          | another blabla  | ...             |...|
```

I do not know of any way (and do not believe one exists) to use the `ng-repeat` directive on the `<tr>` element and generate the desired table without first transforming the data structure.

I therefore need to extract all the branches conditions to feed the `ng-repeat`. So far, I have created recursively an `exampleFlattenTree` for `ng-repeat` to iterate over as follows:

```
exampleFlattenTree = flatten(exampleTree);

flatten = function (dataNode) {
    var flattenTree = [];

    if (dataNode.tree && dataNode.tree.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dataNode.tree.length; i++) {
            var flattenChildren = flatten(dataNode.tree[i]);
            for (var j = 0; j < flattenChildren.length; j++) {
                flattenTree.push([dataNode.condition].concat(flattenChildren[j]));
            }
        }
    } else {
        flattenTree.push(dataNode.condition);
    }
    return flattenTree;
}
```

However, I am not convinced this is the best approach. This seems to be overly complicated. Is there a more elegant (correct?) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy to see that someone ask it, my answer is somehow more general but I hope it would answer your question.

I often see newbies screwing around with `ngRepeat` trying to hack it out in such bizarre ways like someone promised that it would feet all use cases whatsoever, and since `ngRepeat` is so dangerous when misused ( because it multiplies your mistakes..) I think it worth a clarification.

This pattern of thinking leads to a big frustration for developers, unreadable hell for code maintainers and a slow and buggy code for end users. It could be even worse if the developer don't understand what angular really does behind the scenes creating a big spaghetti of scopes, tons of watchers and sloppy key references that break with a touch of a feather.

> I am not convinced this is the best approach. This seems to be overly complicated.

Given the fact that you need to support a rich complex recursive object type, your solution is the least complicated, trying to `ngRepeat` it would be an overkill.

UI data bindings are easy with simple data structures, always restructure your data before you bind it to a scope.

The whole thing about angular.js is that it awesome! we need to stop making it lame!!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I will keep it the way I have done it then.